# I get false hour and minute in java

Tags: java

I try to get the current time and hour in java:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import  java.util.Date;
public class Clock2
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int minute;
    private int hour;
    private String daytime;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Clock2
     */
    public Clock2()
    {   
        Date date = new Date(); 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        this.hour = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
        this.minute = Calendar.MINUTE;
    }
```

But somehow for now `13.33` i get hour `11` an minute `12` what do i wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Somehow i always get the same minute an hour!

Comment: It should be `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its giving right answer

```
import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Date;

 public class Clock2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock clock = new Clock();
}

}

class Clock {
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Clock2
 */
private final int minute;
private final int hour;

public Clock() {
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    System.out.println(hour + " " + minute);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and `Calendar.MINUTE` are simply integer constants, which you must use to get the appropriate *field* of the calendar instance:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is constant

Answer (score 2):

You get hour and minute incorrectly. Try.

```
    this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use are using the Calendar API incorrect:

- At the moment you are accessing `static int` fields of the Calendar class, i.e. [`Calendar.HOUR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR).
- To get the correct time/ date use the [`get(int field)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method of the Calendar class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. You need to change

`int hour = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
        int minute = Calendar.MINUTE;`

by

`this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);`

Answer (score 0):

Getting current hour in java

```
private String getDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); // Choose your time format
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Joda Time instead of standard java.util.Date classes. Joda Time library has much better API for handling dates.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();  // current time
int month = dt.getMonth();     // gets the current month
int hours = dt.getHourOfDay(); // gets hour of day
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes java.time classes. Now supplanted by the java.time classes. In particular, the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

A time zone is required to determine the current time of day. The date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone for any given moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z );
int hour = lt.getHour();
int minute = lt.getMinute();
```